# Multiple form submition in spring mvc 3.0

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

i want to show entered data of user in a registration form (like preview page) to confirm correctness of entered data and if they accept, then that data should go into the database.

here is my controller code:

```
@RequestMapping( value="/catalogue/FormPreview.action", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView onSubmit(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object command,CatalogueBase catalogueBase) throws Exception {

        if(catalogueBase.getTitleNumber()!= null)
        {
            request.setAttribute("titleNo", catalogueBase.getTitleNumber());
            request.setAttribute("title", catalogueBase.getTitle());
            request.setAttribute("name", catalogueBase.getName());
            request.setAttribute("address", catalogueBase.getAddress());
            request.setAttribute("email", catalogueBase.getEmail());

                     .....

            return new ModelAndView("catalogue/catalogueFormPreview","catalogueBase",catalogueBase);
        }
        else
        {
            return create(catalogueBase);
        }
    }

    @RequestMapping( value="/catalogue/create.action", method=RequestMethod.POST)
        public ModelAndView create(@ModelAttribute CatalogueBase catalogueForm) throws Exception {  
            ModelAndView mvc = null;

            try{

                List<CatalogueBase> catalogueBases =  new ArrayList<CatalogueBase>(); //getCatalogueBase(request);
                catalogueBases.add(catalogueForm);
                List<CatalogueBase> catalogueBaseList = catalogueService.create(catalogueBases);
                mvc =   new ModelAndView("catalogue/catalogueList");

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return mvc;
        }
```

and I show the preview page as jsp using EL like:

```
    Title NO : ${titleNo}
    Title : ${title}
    ......
    ......

   <a onclick="doAjaxPost();">Confirm Data<span class="icon icon44"></a>
```

and in the head section of the jsp I am calling ajax like:

```
<script>
function doAjaxPost() {
    var name = $('#name').val();
    var education = $('#education').val();
    var str = $("#form").serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../catalogue/create.action",
        data: str,
        success: function(response){
         alert("Record Added Successfully");
         },
         error: function(e){
             alert('Error: ' + e);
         }
    });
};
```

it is showing data on preview page, but after clicking on confirm data, (hyperlink in preview page)
it sends null values to the create method(Second method) please can anyone tell why it's sending nulls and how I can solve this

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Preview Page, you are only displaying the text, you need to get your data there as well in preview page either as hidden(or by any other means, like saving in session if much entries are there then etc). so that when you submit after confirmation, you can read all parameters.